# VSTS build agent failed to clean up folder

Tags: git, build, azure-devops, agent

If anyone get this error "Unable to run "git clean -fdx" and "git reset --hard HEAD" successfully, delete source folder instead."

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your build machine.
2. Go to the build folder and trace what application is blocking the build folder.
3. Kill the application.
   This occurred when you create a build and then cancel immediately.